# "emacs-c" tag for talking about Emacs's own C?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I noticed that there is a tag "[c](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c)" but I assume that is meant to describe questions/posts having to do with "using Emacs to write C code" rather than "understanding and patching the C code that underpins Emacs."  Could we have an [emacs-c](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-c) tag for the latter purpose?

Comment: Indeed [tag:c] is about the C code in general (editing it, compiling it, etc.), following [this meta discussion](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/192/should-tags-be-named-after-the-item-or-the-corresponding-emacs-mode-related-to-t). Tags are created the first time a question warranting them is posted, is there a question which warrants an [tag:emacs-c] tag (if that's the name we choose)? Note that you have enough reputation to create a tag.

Comment: [done](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12935/dribble-keystrokes-with-timestamp) and [done](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/emacs-c/info).  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We now have at least three tags which have similar meanings:

- [emacs-internals](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-internals)
- [emacs-development](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-development)
- your new [emacs-c](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-c)

I think the intention of [emacs-development](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-development) is to be about upstream development, C and Lisp alike — submitting patches, release history, etc. I don't see a meaningful distinction between [emacs-internals](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-internals) and [emacs-c](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-c), although the usage of the tag seems to be all over the place.

My proposal:

- Clarify in the tag wiki that [emacs-internals](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-internals) is about the parts of Emacs that you can't access from Lisp, i.e. the C code.
- Make [emacs-c](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-c) a synonym of [emacs-internals](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-internals)
- Clarify in the tag wiki that [emacs-development](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-development) is about upstream development procedures.
- Retag questions that don't match this as appropriate.

Comment: I agree with this. If anyone would care to clean up the `emacs-internals` tag I'll be glad to setup the synonym.